# Characterization of one-to-one conformal mapping from unit disc onto a square

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis, chapter 14 exercise 22.

> Suppose $f$ is a one-to-one conformal mapping of $U$ onto a square with center at $0$, and $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $f(iz) = if(z)$. If $f(z) = \sum c_n z^n$, prove that $c_n = 0$ unless $n - 1$ is a multiple of $4$. Generalize this: Replace the square by other simply connected regions with rotational symmetry.

The part about $c_n = 0$ is easy once the first part is proved. This is were I'm stuck. I suspect the generalization will become easier once I know how to prove the first part. Any help is appreciated.

Notes:

- This is not homework. I'm reading the text on my own.
- $U$ is the unit disc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $g(z)=f^{-1}(if(z))$ is a conformal 1-1 map from $U$ onto itself fixing the origin. Try playing a little with this or something similar.

Comment: I applied Schwarz lemma and solved the general case with ease. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterM well done!

Comment: This yields that $f^{-1}(if(z))=\lambda z$ for some constant $|\lambda|=1$. How do we show $\lambda = i$?

Comment: @mrf Unfortunately, I am unable to see how this helps. Do you mind elaborating a bit? Thank you.

Comment: @user122916 Do you have any idea now? I'm thinking about this too.

Comment: @mrf I'm sorry, I still don't understand why the second equality hold, it is equivalent to $if(z)=f(iz)$, since f is 1-1?

Comment: @Ylath I verified it by computing the derivative at $0$. Indeed, since $f^{-1}(if(z))=\lambda z$, we can compute that $(f^{-1})'(0)\cdot i\cdot f'(0)=\lambda$. But since $f^{-1}(f(z))=z$, we compute that $(f^{-1})'(0)\cdot f'(0)=1$. Combining this information yields $\lambda =i$.

Comment: @user122916 I think you have an issue if $f^{\prime}(0)=0$. Instead you can note $i f(z) = f(\lambda z)$, differentiate that, and use that $f^{\prime}$ is not identically zero.